# How can I get a list of Amazon QuickSight resources owned by a specific user?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I need to remove a certain Amazon QuickSight user but before that I need to get a list of any resources they may own. Any suggestions on how that can be done?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for how to do this. I've found that you can use `search_*` functions in the boto3 library to find analyses and dashboards.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.search_analyses